# How do I retrieve the layout field from the parent page?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid

I want to know what the layout of the parent page is in my fluid template.

So in the template I've added:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.parentLayout" data="{uid: {data.pid}}" />
```

But I am not sure what to do in typoscript:

```
lib.parentLayout = CONTENT
lib.parentLayout {
    table = pages
    select {
        uid.data = field:uid
        fieldName = layout
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different options to get that information.

You could for example add the field layout to the so called `rootline fields` https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/Configuration/Typo3ConfVars/FE.html#globals-typo3-conf-vars-fe-addrootlinefields and make use of the level functionality of getText:

```
lib.parentLayout  = TEXT
lib.parentLayout  {
  data = levelfield:-2, layout
}
```

or you could use the PID (aka parent parent ID) to get the parent page with CONTENT:

```
lib.parentLayout = CONTENT
lib.parentLayout {
  table = pages
  select {
    uidInList.field = pid
    pidInList = 0
    selectFields = layout
  }
  renderObj = TEXT
  renderObj.field = layout
}
```

or with RECORDS:

```
lib.parentLayout = RECORDS
lib.parentLayout {
  tables = pages
  source.field = pid
  conf.pages = TEXT
  conf.pages {
    field = layout
  }
}
```

and of course you can go for setting UID with PID in the Fluid template, but IMHO this is misleading.

Comment: Thank you. The getText option seems to work without adding it to rootline fields. Perhaps that is only necessary for custom fields?